# SQL - Count Entries from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have the following tables:

```
Table A:
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
|  name1 |
|  name2 |
|  name3 |
+--------+

Table B:
+--------+----------+
| name   | someB    | 
+--------+----------+
|  name1 |    dorem |
|  name1 |    lorem |
|  name3 |    ipsum |
+--------+----------+

Table C:
+--------+----------+
| name   | someC    | 
+--------+----------+
|  name1 |    dorem |
|  name2 |    lorem |
|  name2 |    ipsum |
+--------+----------+
```

How would the SQL look like to count the entries from the bottom two tables for each *name*?

The result should look like this:

```
+--------+----+----+
| name   | A  | B  | 
+--------+----+----+
|  name1 |  2 |  1 |
|  name2 |  0 |  2 |
|  name3 |  1 |  0 |
+--------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
select name,
    (select count(*) from table2 t2 where t2.name = t1.name) as A,
    (select count(*) from table3 t3 where t3.name = t1.name) as B
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a problem with your data structure.  If the first table has unique ids for the names, then this should be used in the subsequent tables.

But in any case, you have `name` in both tables where you want to do the counts.  You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select name, sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b
from ((select name, 1 as a, 0 as b from t2) union all
      (select name, 0, 1 from t3)
     ) t
group by name;
```

Comment: For a beginner, the description of denormalization won't be very compelling. May I suggest a more detailed description of what you mean by using unique IDs in subsequent tables, and why this matters, what the pitfalls are of not doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.name, COUNT(A.name),     COUNT(B.Name) 
   FROM C
   LEFT JOIN A ON C.name = A.name
   LEFT JOIN B ON C.name = B.name
   GROUP BY C.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.Name, B2.Nb as A, C2.Nb as B

from A

inner join lateral 
(
select count(*) Nb from B where B.Name=A.Name
) B2 on 1=1

inner join lateral 
(
select count(*) Nb from C where C.Name=A.Name
) C2 on 1=1
```